# How to include content of the html file to template of the jenkins email-ext?

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I am using Jenkins and email-ext to send build notifications. Build produces small custom report stored as simple HTML in `out` directory. Right now I can easy attach this report to the email, but what I want is to have this report rendered to the email body itself. I know that I can write my own jelly template, but this requires access to the build server(to install jelly script), I want to avoid this too. So my questions are:

1. Can I include content of the arbitrary file(generated during build) to Content field of the Email-Ext plugin?
2. If I cannot, what is most easy way to send such report in Jenkins?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load HTML File Contents to Div \[without the use of iframes\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535055/load-html-file-contents-to-div-without-the-use-of-iframes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like most easy way is to use 'Pre-send Script' of the Email-ext

Script looks like this:

```
def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("HealthTestResults.html")
msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html");
```

It renders content of the HealthTestResults.html located in the root of the workspace just as body of the message.

Comment: Is there a way to run a script in build.getWorkspace()? I'd like to process TEST*.xml files.

Comment: @Noel Yap - Your best method for processing XML files to HTML is to add an XSL process to your build. And then include the the output as the inline attachment (see above).

Comment: This code is working for me , but now my problem is , there is one attachment (specified in "Attachments" section of the plugin ) which is missing

Answer (score 5):

Easy way to include the html file to email content is to add below line in the default content = ${FILE, path="yourfilename.html"}

this works for me in jenkins email ext  plugin

Answer (score 0):

**If you use groovy template, then you can do something like this**

```
stage("Notifications") {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.ForEmailPlugin = env.WORKSPACE

                    emailext mimeType: "text/html",
                        body: '''${SCRIPT, template="notification.template"}''',
                        subject: env.JENKINS_PROJECT + " " + currentBuild.currentResult + " : " + env.JOB_NAME + "/" + env.GIT_COMMIT,
                        recipientProviders: [requestor(), developers()],
                        from: env.JENKINS_EMAIL,
                        attachLog: true
                }
            }
        }
```

and slice of **/var/lib/jenkins/email-templates/notification.template**

```
<!-- ARGOCD SYNC OUTPUT -->
<h3>ArgoCD<h3/>
<hr size="1" />
<tt>
${new File("/tmp/sync.txt").text.replaceAll('\n','<br>').replaceAll(' ', '&nbsp;')}
</tt>
```