# Load a <div> in a page from a separate HTML file using .append() - possible?

Tags: jquery, html, load, append

I'm currently using .append() to add a div to page. However, I was hoping to be able to be a bit more streamlined and load the div in from completely separate HTML file rather that hold div and content within the JS file.

Here's what I have currently:

jQuery:

```
$('.addNewContent').click(function() {
$( '#content' ).append( "new content" );
return false;
});
```

I've seen there's already been a question that's related, however no inclination as to how it's implemented - [Load HTML File Contents to Div [without the use of iframes]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535055/load-html-file-contents-to-div-without-the-use-of-iframes)

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's `.load()` function.

Comment: As a sidenote, ajax is great, but loading another HTML file can make your site more "streamlined", or it can screw it up royally, depends on what you're doing !

Comment: It's to basically to not make the .js file bloated. It's not overly technical what I'm trying to achieve - just a bit beyond my skillset :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function:

```
$('.addNewContent').click(function(e) {
    $( "#content" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Note that it may take a while to load the actual content; Also it will replace contents within `#content`, but you may create another element inside, and load contents to it instead:

```
$("<div></div>").appendTo("content").load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the html file is on the same server...

```
$(".addNewContent").click(function() {
    $("#content").load("other-page.html #containerID");
    return false;
});
```

That will load the other html page and put the contents of `#containerID` into `#content`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.get()` function:

```
$('.addNewContent').click(function() {
    $.get("/path/to/file", function(data) {   
       $("#content").append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```