# Load HTML content as text into div?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this code to grab html stored in a string into a div with contenteditable="true" (the string works, and if I manually place the code there it also works, but I need a way to "inject" html or whatever as text in it)

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=txt
```

Problem is: It's not placing the html as text inside of it, but executing like it was part of the page. Is there a way around it? I need the HTML(javascript or whatever be written in the string) to be like text...

Comment: did you tried innerText ?

Comment: Are you looking for this...  document.getElementById("content").value =txt;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load HTML File Contents to Div \[without the use of iframes\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535055/load-html-file-contents-to-div-without-the-use-of-iframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textContent` instead to inject strings like this:

```
document.getElementById('content').textContent=txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `textContent` property:

```
document.getElementById('content').textContent = txt
```

for more information give a look [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/textContent)