# How do I separate the HTML markup in my custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I have a custom element that displays a message inside three nested divs:

```js
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const div1 = document.createElement('div')
        this.appendChild(div1)
        
        const div2 = document.createElement('div')
        div1.appendChild(div2)
        
        const div3 = document.createElement('div')
        div3.textContent = 'Hello World!';
        div2.appendChild(div3)
    }
}
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld)
```

It works, but I'm not happy with having all of the HTML markup inside of strings. I want to separate the HTML markup from the JavaScript, preferably in a separate file so that my IDE can give me better support. Here's an example of how I want to separate them:

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="inner-div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        const innerDiv = this.getElementById('inner-div')
        innerDiv .textContent = 'Hello World!';
    }
}
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld)
```

Is it possible to separate them like this?

Comment: To load html content from external HTML file, you could use jQuery function load(). Reference: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @MingzeLi Yea, that seems like it would work. It would require another trip to the server though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load HTML File Contents to Div \[without the use of iframes\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535055/load-html-file-contents-to-div-without-the-use-of-iframes)

Comment: The ``<template>`` element? And for loading external content; see [my ``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a way to achieve this in the past, but it was removed from the specification, and subsequently, from browsers as well (e.g. Chrome removed it in Chrome 70). It was called `HTML imports` and it originally was part of the web components specs.

Currently they are working on a replacement for this obviously lacking platform feature, which will be called `HTML modules`. Here's [the explainer](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/blob/gh-pages/proposals/html-modules-explainer.md). Chances are the syntax is going to look similar to this:

```
  import {content} from "import.html";
```

Resolving the remaining issues with HTML modules I assume might take quite some time, so until then the only viable option you have is to have either your build stack resolve the issue for you (e.g. with webpack-raw-loader), or to rely on async `fetch` to get the job done (which might result in a less-than-optimal performance experience).

We already have [JSON modules](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-modules) and [CSS module scripts](https://web.dev/css-module-scripts/) (which both were sorely missing features for a long time as well).